# Javascript function do before ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wcf

I have one function use for showing cart list that user added to their cart.

First, items are displayed from localStorage, when user not yet log in.

The displayed items will change its detail, those detail are from web service whenever the user log in successfully.

Item details in localStorage and web service can be different, due to the price level of each user. So I want to compare items detail in localStorage and item detail from web service, If it is different from each other, then delete all those data in localStorage, and set new data get from web service to  localStorage instead.

Here what I have tried :

```
this.showItem = function(){

 var cartObject = self.getCartObjectFromLocalStorage(); //get all data from localStorage

 var result = "";
 $.ajax({
     url:"urlstring",
     type:"POST",
     dataType:"json",
     contentType: "application/json",
     data : JSON.stringify(cartObject),
     success:function(res){
        result = res;
     },
     error:function(res){
        result="";
     },
     async : false
 });

 if((JSON.stringify(cartObject.CartLists) === JSON.stringify(result) == false)){ //if data in localStorage not equal data get from web service
     self.deleteAllItemInLocalStorage();
     window.localStorage.setItem(localStorage_.Cart,serializeObjToJSON(result));
 }
 return result;
}
```

`result` that get from web service will empty when function `deleteAllItemInLocalStorage()` do. But what I want is `result` still store the data that get from web service.

How could I delete all data in localStorage, but the result is something from web service.

Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like a lot of this logic should be implemented in the server Domo, and then get the data again from the server, and everything should work :)

Comment: @HanletEscaño : Data get from the server is fine, just my delete function works before the ajax request works, so ajax will be error when data is wrong format.